# Query and select over branches using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to get an XML document containing NAME, FIRSTNAME and STR of all entries where ZIP=2222 and the NAME=Meier.

The input is:

```
<ROOT> 
<REC>
  <CONTACT>
    <NAME>Schmidt</NAME>
    <FIRSTNAME>Hans</FIRSTNAME>
  </CONTACT>
  <CONTACT>
    <NAME>Schmidt</NAME>
    <FIRSTNAME>Kurt</FIRSTNAME>
  </CONTACT>
  <LOC>
    <ZIP>1111</ZIP>
    <STR>Mainroud</STR>
  </LOC>
</REC>
<REC>
  <CONTACT>
    <NAME>Meier</NAME>
    <FIRSTNAME>Elise</FIRSTNAME>
  </CONTACT>
  <LOC>
    <ZIP>2222</ZIP>
    <STR>Castlestreet</STR>
  </LOC>
</REC>
</ROOT>
```

The desired output:

```
 <OUT>
    <NAME>Meier</NAME>
    <FIRSTNAME>Elise</FIRSTNAME>
    <STR>Castlestreet</STR>
 </OUT>
```

I tried:

```
/ROOT/REC[.//ZIP="2222" and .//NAME/text()="Meier"]
```

Which returns the matching REC elements, but how can I format the output.
I would like to use Xpath only, not Xquery if possible?

Comment: It is impossible using XPath only. XPath is just a simple expression to get specific part of XML..

Comment: It would be easy using XSLT, even version 1.0.

Comment: Is `<STR>Mainroad</STR>` correct? Or would it rather be `<STR>Castlestreet</STR>` in the desired output?

Comment: this was a bug, corrected it. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is specify which nodes you want to have in your output, but those will not be included into an `<OUT>` node, because there's none in original XML.
In case you want a list of specific nodes you'll have to alter your XPath to something like this:

```
/ROOT/REC[.//ZIP="2222" and .//NAME/text()="Meier"]//(NAME|ZIP|STR)
```

Which will give you following result:

```
<NAME>Meier</NAME>
<ZIP>2222</ZIP>
<STR>Castlestreet</STR>
```

The result is nodes collection, not single node with child nodes, you'll have to iterate over the collection. Not exactly what you were asking for, but closes what I could come up with using only XPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
      let $input :=doc("input.xml")/ROOT/REC[.//ZIP="2222" and 
     .//NAME/text()="Meier"]
     return <OUT>{($input//NAME, $input//FIRSTNAME,  $input//STR)}</OUT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nice solution is:

```
//REC[.//ZIP="2222" and .//NAME/text()="Meier"]
!<OUT>
  {.//NAME}
  {.//STR}
  {.//ZIP}
</OUT>
```