# Has XQuery an AS statement like SQL to change return element name e.g. of a union

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have two XML Documents and want to create a union.
The two documents have a different formats.

Doc1:

```
<contact>
  <realName>Kurt Meier</realName>
  <phone number="017289232"></phone>
</contact>
```

Doc2:

```
<Person>
  <Name>Susie</Name>
  <FirstName>Meier</FirstName>
  <Phone>0173895734</Phone>
</Person>
```

The desired output shall be normalized.
Where FULLNAME is realName in case of an  element,
And FULLNAME is Name concatenated with FirstName in case of an  element.

```
<CONTACT>
  <FULLNAME>Kurt Meier</FULLNAME>
  <PHONE_NO>017289232<PHONE_NO> 
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
  <FULLNAME>Susie Meier</FULLNAME>
  <PHONE_NO>0173895734<PHONE_NO> 
</CONTACT>
```

In sql it would look like:

```
select 
   realName               as FULLNAME,
   number                 as PHONE_NO
from  Doc1
union all
select 
   FirstName ||' '|| Name as FULLNAME,
   phone                  as PHONE_NO
from  Doc2
```

I know that I can create a union using comma separated xpaths:

```
 for $e in (doc("Doc1.xml")//contact, doc("Doc2.xml")//Person)
 return $e
```

but I do not manage to change the returned element names like with the AS statement in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct new elements, in case of XQuery 3 the most compact syntax is

```
doc("Doc1.xml")//contact!<CONTACT><FULLNAME>{realName}</FULLNAME><PHONE_NO>{phone/@number}/</PHONE_NO></CONTACT>,
doc("Doc2.xml")//Person!<CONTACT><FULLNAME>{Name} {FirstName}</FULLNAME><PHONE_NO>{Phone}/</PHONE_NO></CONTACT>
```

Comment: @Hanspeter, yes, you are right, being more of an XSLT person where an `xsl:value-of` or a text value template `{}` would create text content I often forget when I move to XQuery that there an enclosed expression in curly braces needs the use of the `data` or `string` function to ensure select nodes are not copied and only the values instead.

Comment: thanks for your idea with using the "exclamation mark" to format the output. It works but I did not found any documents explaining it, Do you have a good link. Meanwhile I added the concept to another issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845856

Comment: XQuery is a W3C recommendation/standard so it is documented online, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-map-operator for the simple map operator `!`. If you want a nice text book for XQuery one option is http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input of Martin Honnen, the solution is:

```
(
doc("Doc1")//contact
!<CONTACT>
  <FULLNAME>{data(realName)}</FULLNAME>
  <PHONE_NO>{data(phone/@number)}/</PHONE_NO>
</CONTACT>,
doc("Doc2")//Person
!<CONTACT>
  <FULLNAME>{data(Name)} {' '} {data(FirstName)}</FULLNAME>
  <PHONE_NO>{data(Phone)}/</PHONE_NO>
</CONTACT>
```

)

Comment: the bang operator introduced in XQuery 3.0 is not need here because for example, //contact is  a sequence of elements so the child path operator / works just as well here.    ! can be applied to a sequence of atoms as well as elements so is more general but is unnecessary in this case.  serialisation of the original elements is however necessary as in this answer,